Why does the PostProcessBuilder only run once?
I have the following PostProcessBuilder
class MoveBuilder extends PostProcessBuilder {

  @override
  Iterable<String> get inputExtensions => ['.g.dart'];

  MoveModelBuilder() ;

  @override
  Future<void> build(PostProcessBuildStep buildStep) async {
    log.info('MOVE THE FILE');
  }
}

And the following top level function
PostProcessBuilder moveSomething(BuilderOptions options) {
  return MoveModelBuilder();
}

With the following build config in my generator package
builders:
  my_builder:
    import: "package:my_package/src/builders/builders.dart"
    builder_factories: ["buildSomething"]
    build_extensions: {'.dart': ['.g.dart']}
    auto_apply: none
    build_to: source
    applies_builders:
      - my_package|move_builder

post_process_builders:
  move_builder:
    import: "package:my_package/src/builders/builders.dart"
    builder_factory: moveSomething

And in my external package where I use this generator I have the following build yaml
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      my_package|my_builder:
        enabled: true
        generate_for:
          - lib/*/input_folder/*.dart
      my_package|move_builder:
        enabled: true
        generate_for:
          - lib/*/relative_output_folder/*.g.dart

But only the first time I run the build runner command the MoveBuilder gets triggered. It seems to only get triggered after this warning
[WARNING] BuildDefinition:
Throwing away cached asset graph because the build phases have changed. This most commonly would happen as a result of adding a new dependency or updating your dependencies.
So after the cached asset graph gets reinitialised.
What can I do to make it run every time after my main builder has ran?
EDIT ----------------------------------------------------
For anyone wanting to move files with a PostProcessBuilder, don't. Use capture groups instead.
https://github.com/dart-lang/build/blob/master/docs/writing_a_builder.md#configuring-output
And here is an example at the bottom
https://github.com/dart-lang/build/blob/master/example/lib/example.dart

Not sure what you expected, but to me the build setup above seems to do what it is supposed to do:

Inital run: dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs --verbose the main builder generates .g.dart files and the post-process builder runs on .g.dart files.

Subsequent build runs will generate output or take actions if for example:

Additional target files are detected.
The generated files were deleted.
A build.yaml file changed.
The file containing a builder changed.
The user deletes the build cache by executing: dart run build_runner clean



Other than that I would expect that building the project a second time should produce: 0 outputs (0 actions).

Well there are additional files, but I guess it's a conflict of name since both the old file have the same content and name but they are at a different path. I'm just going to mark the newly generate files as a temp file which should resolve the issue then. That aside where did you find the info for point 2? Thanks for the answer.

I tried each item listed under point 2 to see if the builder produces any output. Btw, I removed the first point. For some reason, my_builder does not run if the content of a target file changes. But move_builder runs if e.g. the content of file lib/src/relative_output_folder/input3.g.dart changes.
